# Win10 constantly making Plug n Play Connect/Disconnect Sound

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, device-manager, plug-and-play

My machine a few months ago started making noises constantly like someone was continually plugging and unplugging a USB device (~10x/hour).  It's affecting my gaming so I finally started trying to figure out what it was.

I wrote a quick script to hook the Win32_PnPEntity class and got the following results as output from the thrown events:

```
\\myPCness\root\CIMV2:Win32_DesktopMonitor.DeviceID="DesktopMonitor1"
\\myPCness\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="DISPLAY\\DEFAULT_MONITOR\\4&12A997EA&0&UID16843008"

\\myPCness\root\CIMV2:Win32_DesktopMonitor.DeviceID="DesktopMonitor2"
\\myPCness\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="DISPLAY\\HWP288E\\5&8E971E&0&UID519"
```

I have 2 monitors each plugged into two separate video cards and I thought maybe one was going to bad so the output you see is me having one plugged in by itself (the first 2 sets of entries) and then me unplugging it and plugging the second monitor into the second video card.  And as you can see, I got the same results...

There's nothing displaying in the App/System event log when they occur and considering I've duplicated the problem across 2 different sets of video cards, hdmi cables, and monitors, I'm at a loss as to explain how to stop the incessant connect/disconnect sounds.

As a side note, I also went through and made sure I had the most up-to-date video driver for the two video cards with no change.

Also, I went through Device Manager before I wrote the hook and turned off the Power Management features of all of my USB Hub -named devices and that didn't help either (I was originally thinking the problem was related to one of the many usb devices plugged into my computer).

Any new looks or directions would be appreciated.  Thx.

Comment: So then... a line conditioner or UPS that does line conditioning?  I'll have to give that a shot and report back.  Thx for the tip.

Comment: Can you submit this as an answer so I can mark as such if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try putting the PC, monitors, and any USB peripherals on a ups. 
this can happen sometimes when excessive noise is on the AC circuit the PSU is attached to.